# MediaWiki 1.29.0 maintenance/update.php does nothing

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

On my hosting with my `MW (1.28.2)` and `SMW (2.5.3)` a have:

1. `/home/www/mediawiki-1.28.2`
2. `/home/www/w -> mediawiki-1.28.2` (link to `mediawiki-1.28.2`)
3. `/home/www/.htaccess`

Following https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Command_line I do:

1. Downloading `mediawiki-1.29.0.tar.gz` to `/home/www/mediawiki-1.29.0.tar.gz`
2. Unpack `mediawiki-1.29.0.tar.gz` to `/home/www/mediawiki-1.29.0`
3. Copy from `/home/www/w` to `/home/www/mediawiki-1.29.0` files and folders: `LocalSettings.php`, `images`, some extensions

Then from command-line I do:

1. Change link `/home/www/w` from `/home/www/mediawiki-1.28.2` to `/home/www/mediawiki-1.29.0`
2. `cd /home/www/w`
3. `/opt/php/7.1/bin/php ~/bin/composer.phar require mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki "~2.5" --update-no-dev`
4. `/opt/php/7.1/bin/php ~/bin/composer.phar update`
5. `/opt/php/7.1/bin/php maintenance/update.php`

And `maintenance/update.php` does nothing! At all!
And my site down to `HTTP 500`.

What is wrong and how can I debug `maintenance/update.php` ?

Comment: Check your error logs for explanation. It will tell you at least the reason for the HTTP 500 (the error output from command-line PHP should be shown in the console; can't think of any reason why there would be no output at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there is how I try to solve it:

1. I removed (temporary) `.htaccess`
2. I switched on error reporting in `LocalSettings.php`
3. When I went to `my website/w/index.php` I found that there were two(!) missing extensions: `PdfHandler` and `SpamBlacklist`. After removing them from `LocalSettings.php` all works fine.

That is the question: where were `PdfHandler` and `SpamBlacklist` gone???

Comment: There is an update 1.29.1: it says, that `PdfHandler` and `SpamBlacklist` are missing

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug

My guess (just a guess) is that there might be a problem with PHP7 as your default, since some MediaWiki extensions don't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some problem with your dependencies try running "composer update" in the terminal and According to me it actually runs Localsettings.php file and aborts if it identifies any errors in the file so you have to check if there is any mistake in it and finally run  php maintanence/update.php in mediawiki directory

Comment: How could be errors in LocalSettigs.php? Before update from 1.28.2 it worked okay